# get locale code from current thread culture

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, currentculture

I am working with a c# application. If I access the

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
```

object, and from inspection I find its culture is set to en-GB, how can I access the GB value? I looked at the object and it was not apparent where such was stored.

Answer (score 5):

Try in this way:

```
var name = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
var locale = name.Split('-')[1];
```

Adapt the code above to check, in case, if the result of `Split()` returns an array with length equals to two. You can also use the `Last()` method from `System.Linq` to obtain the last element of it without having to relay on the index.